# В проекте Unity в скрипте не могу присоединить библиотеку System.ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, xml, config

Пытаюсь в проекте использовать xml-файл для хранения характеристик персонажа, но столкнулся с проблемой. Из-за того, что создаю все файлы скриптов в окне Unity, у меня в обозревателе решений нет ни элемента зависимостей, ни элемента ссылок. Как я потом узнал, в текущем патче C#, или что то вроде того, нужно использовать Nuget, но при этом я не могу его подключить к этому скрипту почему то. Попытался даже вручную впихнуть в проект эту библиотеку, но нет эффекта.

Как мне подключить библиотеку ConfigurationManager?

Код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

public class MC_stats : MonoBehaviour
{
public struct MC
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Health;
        public int Willpower;
        public int Body;
        public int Strength;
        public int Speed;
        public int Skill;
        public int Intuition;
        public int Faith;
    }
    public void Start()
    {

string Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"];
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем характеристикам персонажа имя приложения? В любом случае может это подойдёт как альтернатива [Application.productName](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-productName.html).

Comment: Смысл даже не в том, чтобы получить имя, а в том, чтобы подключить библиотеку ConfigManager, так как в файле xml хранятся все другие характеристики

Comment: Похоже что System.Configuration совсем не поддерживается в Unity,  т. к. версия Mono слишком старая. Быть может, если знать, что конкретно нужно из AppSettings, то можно найти эти данные каким-нибудь другим способом?

Comment: Не поддерживается? В таком случае вопрос наверное можно закрывать. Мне нужно из созданного мной кофиг файла получить значения. Именно для этого я хотел использовать эту библиотеку

Comment: Для чтения XML есть другие средства, в System.Xml много всякого добра.

Comment: попробую использовать System.Xml, благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил использовать System.Xml.Linq, оно даже работает.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/823972)

Comment: Я и есть автор. Мне удалить вопрос или оставить его как есть, без ответа?

Comment: Отредактируйте ответ и предоставьте больше деталей, как именно вы использовали `Xml.Linq` для решения возникшей проблемы с конфигурацией, чтобы от ответа было больше пользы.  А так у вас фактически получился комментарий типа "Спасибо" к тому, что вам посоветовали в комментариях к вопросу.